# Probability of no kings and at least one queen

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to make a explain a counting problem. What would be the probability of getting no king and at least one queen in a poker hand ?

I initially approached the question as the following but am not sure if it is correct: $$\frac{{\binom{4}1}{\binom{47}1} + {\binom{4}2}{\binom{46}2} + {\binom{4}3}{\binom{45}2} + {\binom{4}1}{\binom{44}1}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$

Basically my way of reasoning was that I had thought that since the probability of getting no kings is given by $$\frac{{\binom{48}5}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$, I thus thought that one could just work from there with the given condition. So, the probability of having exactly one queen would be given by: $$\frac{{\binom{4}1}*{\binom{47}1}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$ since one must draw one queen and has 47 remaining cards to choose from. Then working from there I took the sum of 2 queens, 3 queens, and 4 queens.
Could someone clarify please ? Perhaps there was an error in my logic somewhere.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by clarification. What is intended is a standard five-card poker hand, drawn from the standard $52$-card deck.

Comment: sorry made a change in the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of getting no king is

$$
\frac{\binom{48}5}{\binom{52}5}=\frac{48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}\;.
$$

The probability of getting no king and no queen is

$$
\frac{\binom{44}5}{\binom{52}5}=\frac{44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot40}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}\;.
$$

Thus the probability of getting no king and at least one queen is

$$
\frac{48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44-44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot40}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}=\frac{78287}{324870}\approx24\%\;.
$$

Comment: Could you explain why it is the case that one cannot use the case where it is: $$\frac{{\binom{4}1}{\binom{47}1} + {\binom{4}2}{\binom{46}2} + {\binom{4}3}{\binom{45}2} + {\binom{4}1}{\binom{44}1}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$ ? Why would this answer not work, I would appreciate some help on explanation as that was how I initially approached the question.

Comment: @TheStudent: Sorry, I can't see the rationale behind that -- you'd have to explain why you thought it could be done like that.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I thought that since the probability of getting no kings is given by $$\frac{{\binom{48}5}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$, I thus thought that one could just work from there with the given condition. So, the probability of having exactly one queen would be given by: $$\frac{{\binom{4}1}*{\binom{47}1}}{{\binom{52}5}}$$ since one must draw one queen and has 47 remaining cards to choose from. Then working from there I took the sum of 2 queens, 3 queens, and 4 queens.

Comment: @TheStudent: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the numerator should be $\binom41\binom{44}4+\binom42\binom{44}3+\binom43\binom{44}2+\binom44\binom{44}1$, and indeed that gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see my error now

Answer (score 0):

The total number of hands is $\binom{52}{5}$, no kings is $\binom{52 - 4}{5}$, no kings and no queens is $\binom{52 - 8}{5}$.

No kings and at least one queen is (no kings) - (no kings and no queens), and the probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{52 - 4}{5} - \binom{52 - 8}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}
    = \frac{48^{\underline{5}} - 44^{\underline{5}}}{52^{\underline{5}}}
    = \frac{190447}{783020} \approx 0.2432$$